# Запрос к api в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо отправить запрос к api яндекса в js для получения и обработки данных. Пытаюсь написать ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/route/2.0/?callback=id_155276244170680561044&lang=ru_RU&token=e150d8d2f888f6936fee0e67ca1ca581&rll=40.186,58.808~45.10,30&rtm=atm&results=3',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
             }
     });
```

Или

```
var url = 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/route/2.0/?callback=id_155276244170680561044&lang=ru_RU&token=e150d8d2f888f6936fee0e67ca1ca581&rll=40.186,58.808~45.10,30&rtm=atm&results=3';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(data);
```

Но никак не могу вывести данные в консоль( Если перейти по этому адресу по адресной строке то все нормально, данные отображаются. Возможно я вообще копаю в другом направлении.

P.S. В консоль падает ошибка:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/route/2.0/?callback=id_155276244170680561044&lang=ru_RU&token=e150d8d2f888f6936fee0e67ca1ca581&rll=40.186,58.808~45.10,30&rtm=atm&results=3' from origin 'http://anew' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

P.S.S. Или это все решается на стороне бэкэнда парсингом?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * нету в ответе сервера...

Answer (score 1):

AJAX имеет ограничения на кросс-доменные запросы (можете [почитать если интересно](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)). Вы не сможете получить данные AJAX-запросом с Яндекса. О чем вам как раз и пишет в консоле. Решается естественно просто - пишите скрипт на PHP в котором будет запрос к API и делаете AJAX-запрос к своему PHP-скрипту. Так вы и получите нужные данные.

Comment: еще проще просто за nginx прокси убрать